# How to rotate an image in android camera preview app before save it?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an Android Camera application thats taken picture in portrait mode, The camera preview is fine ... but when i taken picture its saved in landscape mode ... its rotate 90 degrees : that my code onPictureTaken():

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + photoFile;

        Log.e("path", filename.toString());

        File pictureFile = new File(filename);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(arg0);
            fos.close();

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
            byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            // sba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
            int flag = 0; // you can pass the default 0 = Base64.DEFAULT
            String ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, flag);

            // Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

            Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this,
                    "New Image saved 22222:" + photoFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidCamera.this,
                    UploadActivity.class);

            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent,
                    CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
            launchUploadActivity(true);

        } catch (Exception error) {
            // Log.d(MakePhotoActivity.DEBUG_TAG, "File" + filename +
            // "not saved: "
            // + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, "Image could not be saved.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate a bitmap 90 degrees like this:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

In your specific example, you need to save it back to the original path:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);    
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
fos.close();
```

You can also use [Camera.Parameters.setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int))

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it throwing an exception? Or just not rotating? did you change your compress() call to rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao); ?

Comment: yes, i have called rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao); .. but it just not rotated !!

Comment: Well, your code is writing the bitmap to a base64 string, I assumed that's what you want. See the edit to answer for how to save the JPEG file rotated.

Comment: I try with this but its throw an exception

Comment: 01-07 02:56:37.736: E/BitmapFactory(17914): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Picture_20155607025637.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) ..

Comment: Yes it Work Thanks,, But in the front camera it roteted to 90 degrees to the top ..!

Comment: You're welcome. You can change the rotation amount by changing the value of matrix.postRotate(90); based on your conditions (front camera or not etc). Good luck!

Comment: BTW, just a small point on the semantics of this answer. This rotates the image *to* the 90th degree which is what most would consider "portrait". This DOES NOT rotate the image *by* 90 degrees.